# from xml to --> mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I trying to write betting script 
so i need odds 
here i trying to get odds and store on my mysql database

```
<?php
$db_host='localhost';
$db_user='karpovci_see';
$db_pass='*****';
$db_name='karpovci_bet';
//establish your connection
$mysqli = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
    // Check connection
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $mysqli->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully";
 //set the variables which you will send to the api call
$data = array();
$data['uid'] = '22489';
$data['key'] = '1dc40';
$data['graded'] = 2; //get both graded and ungraded games
$data['sports'] = 'Baseball-MLB,Basketball-NCAA,Basketball-NBA,Football-NCAA,Football-NFL,Hockey-NHL';

$target_url = 'http://api.pickmonitor.com/lines.php';

$response = http($target = $target_url,'','GET',$data,EXCL_HEAD);
$content = $response['FILE'];
echo 'test'; <----- here code stop 
if($content == false)
{
    echo 'An error has occured.';
    exit();
}
else
{
    //use the simplexml library to do wonderous things
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($content);
    $lines = array();
    foreach ($xml->lines->game as $game)
    {

        if($game->line->score->winner)
        {
            //the game has been graded, so let's process all of the bets on the game
        }
        else
        {
            //the game hasn't been graded, so let's update the lines
            //you could do various checks like checking to make sure te game hasn't already started,
            //but as long as you don't pass full_call = 1 then we do those checks for you on our side

            //first let's check to see if the game is already in our datbase.
            $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT id FROM games WHERE id = ".$game->id);
            if($result->num_rows == 0)
            {
                //the game isn't in our databse, so let's insert it
                $mysql->real_query("INSERT INTO lines VALUES(
                    '$game->id',
                    '$game->sporttype',
                    '$game->sportsubtype',
                    '$game->gamedate',
                    '$game->last_update',
                    '$game->team1->rotnum',
                    '$game->team1->name',
                    '$game->team1->pitcher',
                    '$game->team2->rotnum',
                    '$game->team2->name',
                    '$game->team2->pitcher',
                    '".$game->line->periodnum."',
                    '".$game->line->perioddesc."',
                    '".$game->line->wagercutoff."',
                    '".$game->line->money->team1."',
                    '".$game->line->money->team2."',
                    '".$game->line->spread->points."',
                    '".$game->line->spread->team1."',
                    '".$game->line->spread->team2."',
                    '".$game->line->total->points."',
                    '".$game->line->total->team1."',
                    '".$game->line->total->team2."',
                    '".$game->line->score->team1."',
                    '".$game->line->score->team2."',
                    '".$game->line->score->winner."'


                )");
            }
            else
            {
                //we already have the game, so let's just update the lines
                $mysql->real_query("UPDATE lines SET
                    sporttype = '$game->sporttype',
                    sportsubtype = '$game->sportsubtype',
                    gamedate = '$game->gamedate',
                    last_update = '$game->last_update',
                    team1rotnum = '$game->team1->rotnum',
                    team1name = '$game->team1->name',
                    team1pitcher = '$game->team1->pitcher',
                    team2rotnum = '$game->team2->rotnum',
                    team2'$game->team2->name',
                    '$game->team2->pitcher',
                    '".$game->line->periodnum."',
                    '".$game->line->perioddesc."',
                    '".$game->line->wagercutoff."',
                    '".$game->line->money->team1."',
                    '".$game->line->money->team2."',
                    '".$game->line->spread->points."',
                    '".$game->line->spread->team1."',
                    '".$game->line->spread->team2."',
                    '".$game->line->total->points."',
                    '".$game->line->total->team1."',
                    '".$game->line->total->team2."',
                    '".$game->line->score->team1."',
                    '".$game->line->score->team2."',
                    '".$game->line->score->winner."'

                WHERE id = ".$game->id);
            }

        }

    }
}


?>
```

but  php stop here

```
 $response = http($target = $target_url,'','GET',$data,EXCL_HEAD);
```

no error no nothink.. 
can sombady help what is wrong in this php code... 
on line 36 echo 'test'; not work...

Comment: What is `http()` function?

Comment: i don't know i take this from this page https://www.pickmonitor.com/xml-odds-feed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://api.pickmonitor.com/lines.php?uid=22489&key=1dc40&graded=2&sports=Baseball-MLB,Basketball-NCAA,Basketball-NBA,Football-NCAA,Football-NFL,Hockey-NHL

have a response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?><lines><game><id>820478</id><header>New York Rangers At Pittsburgh Penguins</header><sporttype>Hockey</sporttype><sportsubtype>NHL</sportsubtype> <gamedate>2015-01-18 12:35:00</gamedate><last_update>2015-01-18 12:30:06</last_update><void>0</void><last_pitcher_change></last_pitcher_change><team1><rotnum>51</rotnum><name>New York Rangers</name><pitcher></pitcher></team1><team2><rotnum>52</rotnum><name>Pittsburgh Penguins</name><pitcher></pitcher> </team2><line><periodnum>0</periodnum><perioddesc>Game</perioddesc><wagercutoff>2015-01-18 12:35:00</wagercutoff><money><team1>123</team1><team2>-133</team2><draw>0</draw></money><spread><points>-1.5</points><team1>-238</team1><team2>218</team2></spread><total><points>5.5</points><over>141</over><under>-151</under></total><teamtotal><team1><points>2.5</points><over>100</over><under>-120</under></team1><team2><points>2.5</points><over>-135</over><under>115</under></team2></teamtotal><score><team1></team1><team2></team2><winner></winner></score></line></game><game><id>820787</id><header>New York Rangers At Pittsburgh Penguins</header><sporttype>Hockey</sporttype><sportsubtype>NHL</sportsubtype> <gamedate>2015-01-18 12:35:00</gamedate><last_update>2015-01-18 12:24:04</last_update><void>0</void><last_pitcher_change></last_pitcher_change><team1><rotnum>51</rotnum><name>New York Rangers</name><pitcher></pitcher></team1><team2><rotnum>52</rotnum><name>Pittsburgh Penguins</name><pitcher></pitcher> </team2><line><periodnum>1</periodnum><perioddesc>1st Period</perioddesc><wagercutoff>2015-01-18 12:30:00</wagercutoff><money><team1>100</team1><team2>-120</team2><draw>0</draw></money><spread><points>-0.5</points><team1>-220</team1><team2>180</team2></spread><total><points>1.5</points><over>110</over><under>-130</under></total><teamtotal><team1><points>0</points><over>0</over><under>0</under></team1><team2><points>0</points><over>0</over><under>0</under></team2></teamtotal><score><team1></team1><team2></team2><winner></winner></score></line></game><game><id>820783</id><header>NHL Grand Salami</header><sporttype>Hockey</sporttype><sportsubtype>NHL</sportsubtype> <gamedate>2015-01-18 12:35:00</gamedate><last_update>2015-01-18 12:09:04</last_update><void>0</void><last_pitcher_change></last_pitcher_change><team1><rotnum>91</rotnum><name>Away Goals Today</name><pitcher></pitcher></team1><team2><rotnum>92</rotnum><name>Home Goals Today</name><pitcher></pitcher> </team2><line><periodnum>0</periodnum><perioddesc>Game</perioddesc><wagercutoff>2015-01-18 12:35:00</wagercutoff><money><team1>335</team1><team2>-420</team2><draw>0</draw></money><spread><points>0</points><team1>0</team1><team2>0</team2></spread><total><points>22.5</points><over>100</over><under>-120</under></total><teamtotal><team1><points>0</points><over>0</over><under>0</under></team1><team2><points>0</points><over>0</over><under>0</under></team2></teamtotal><score><team1></team1><team2></team2><winner></winner></score></line></game><game><id>820470</id><header>Indiana U At Illinois</header><sporttype>Basketball</sporttype><sportsubtype>College</sportsubtype> <gamedate>2015-01-18 13:00:00</gamedate><last_update>2015-01-18 12:45:07</last_update><void>0</void><last_pitcher_change></last_pitcher_change><team1><rotnum>807</rotnum><name>Indiana U</name><pitcher></pitcher></team1><team2><rotnum>808</rotnum><name>Illinois</name><pitcher></pitcher> </team2><line><periodnum>0</periodnum><perioddesc>Game</perioddesc><wagercutoff>2015-01-18 13:00:00</wagercutoff><money><team1>210</team1><team2>-230</team2><draw>0</draw></money><spread><points>-5.5</points><team1>-105</team1><team2>-105</team2></spread><total><points>143.5</points><over>-105</over><under>-105</under></total><teamtotal><team1><points>69</points><over>-110</over><under>-110</under></team1><team2><points>74.5</points><over>-110</over><under>-110</under></team2></teamtotal><score><team1></team1><team2></team2><winner></winner></score></line></game><game><id>820486</id><header>Rider At Manhattan</header><sporttype>Basketball</sporttype><sportsubtype>College</sportsubtype> <gamedate>2015-01-18 14:00:00</gamedate><last_update>2015-01-18 12:30:12</last_update><void>0</void><last_pitcher_change></last_pitcher_change><team1><rotnum>829</rotnum><name>Rider</name><pitcher></pitcher></team1><team2><rotnum>830</rotnum><name>Manhattan</name><pitcher></pitcher> </team2><line><periodnum>0</periodnum><perioddesc>Game</perioddesc><wagercutoff>2015-01-18 14:00:00</wagercutoff><money><team1>140</team1><team2>-150</team2><draw>0</draw></money><spread><points>-3</points><team1>-105</team1><team2>-105</team2></spread><total><points>125</points><over>-110</over><under>-110</under></total><teamtotal><team1><points>0</points><over>0</over><under>0</under></team1><team2><points>0</points><over>0</over><under>0</under></team2></teamtotal><score><team1></team1><team2></team2><winner></winner></score></line></game><game><id>820485</id><header>IUPUI At Nebraska Omaha</header><sporttype>Basketball</sporttype><sportsubtype>College</sportsubtype> <gamedate>2015-01-18 14:00:00</gamedate><last_update>2015-01-18 12:18:04</last_update><void>0</void><last_pitcher_change></last_pitcher_change><team1><rotnum>827</rotnum><name>IUPUI</name><pitcher></pitcher></team1><team2><rotnum>828</rotnum><name>Nebraska Omaha</name><pitcher></pitcher> </team2><line><periodnum>0</periodnum><perioddesc>Game</perioddesc><wagercutoff>2015-01-18 14:00:00</wagercutoff><money><team1>310</team1><team2>-340</team2><draw>0</draw></money><spread><points>-7.5</points><team1>-105</team1><team2>-105</team2></spread><total><points>146.5</points><over>-110</over><under>-110</under></total><teamtotal><team1><points>0</points><over>0</over><under>0</under></team1><team2><points>0</points><over>0</over><under>0</under></team2></teamtotal><score><team1></team1><team2></team2><winner></winner></score></line></game><game><id>820862</id><header>Siena At Niagra</header><sporttype>Basketball</sporttype><sportsubtype>College</sportsubtype> <gamedate>2015-01-18 14:00:00</gamedate><last_update>2015-01-18 12:15:07</last_update><void>0</void><last_pitcher_change></last_pitcher_change><team1><rotnum>823</rotnum><name>Siena</name><pitcher></pitcher></team1><team2><rotnum>824</rotnum><name>Niagara</name><pitcher></pitcher> </team2><line><periodnum>0</periodnum><perioddesc>Game</perioddesc><wagercutoff>2015-01-18 14:00:00</wagercutoff><money><team1>130</team1><team2>-140</team2><draw>0</draw></money><spread><points>-2.5</points><team1>-105</team1><team2>-105</team2></spread><total><points>0</points><over>0</over><under>0</under></total><teamtotal><team1><points>0</points><over>0</over><under>0</under></team1><team2><points>0</points><over>0</over><under>0</under></team2></teamtotal><score><team1></team1><team2></team2><winner></winner></score></line></game><game><id>820863</id><header>Siena At Niagra</header><sporttype>Basketball</sporttype><sportsubtype>College</sportsubtype> <gamedate>2015-01-18 14:00:00</gamedate><last_update>2015-01-18 12:15:07</last_update><void>0</void><last_pitcher_change></last_pitcher_change><team1><rotnum>823</rotnum><name>Siena</name><pitcher></pitcher></team1><team2><rotnum>824</rotnum><name>Niagara</name><pitcher></pitcher> </team2><line><periodnum>1</periodnum><perioddesc>1st Half</perioddesc><wagercutoff>2015-01-18 13:55:00</wagercutoff><money><team1>115</team1><team2>-135</team2><draw>0</draw></money><spread><points>-1.5</points><team1>-115</team1><team2>-105</team2></spread><total><points>0</points><over>0</over><under>0</under></total><teamtotal><team1><points>0</points><over>0</over><under>0</under></team1><team2><points>0</points><over>0</over><under>0</under></team2></teamtotal><score><team1></team1><team2></team2><winner></winner></score></line></game><game><id>820473</id><header>St. John's At DePaul</header><sporttype>Basketball</sporttype><sportsubtype>College</sportsubtype> <gamedate>2015-01-18 14:30:00</gamedate><last_update>2015-01-18 12:24:04</last_update><void>0</void><last_pitcher_change></last_pitcher_change><team1><rotnum>813</rotnum><name>St. John's</name><pitcher></pitcher></team1><team2><rotnum>814</rotnum><name>DePaul</name><pitcher></pitcher> </team2><line><periodnum>0</periodnum><perioddesc>Game</perioddesc><wagercutoff>2015-01-18 14:30:00</wagercutoff><money><team1>-250</team1><team2>230</team2><draw>0</draw></money><spread><points>6</points><team1>-105</team1><team2>-105</team2></spread><total><points>145</points><over>-105</over><under>-105</under></total><teamtotal><team1><points>75.5</points><over>-110</over><under>-110</under></team1><team2><points>69.5</points><over>-110</over><under>-110</under></team2></teamtotal><score><team1></team1><team2></team2><winner></winner></score></line></game><game><id>820474</id><header>St. Joseph's At St. Bonaventure</header><sporttype>Basketball</sporttype><sportsubtype>College</sportsubtype> <gamedate>2015-01-18 14:30:00</gamedate><last_update>2015-01-18 12:30:12</last_update><void>0</void><last_pitcher_change></last_pitcher_change><team1><rotnum>815</rotnum><name>St. Joseph's</name><pitcher></pitcher></team1><team2><rotnum>816</rotnum><name>St. Bonaventure</name><pitcher></pitcher> </team2><line><periodnum>0</periodnum><perioddesc>Game</perioddesc><wagercutoff>2015-01-18 14:30:00</wagercutoff><money><team1>225</team1><team2>-245</team2><draw>0</draw></money><spread><points>-6</points><team1>-105</team1><team2>-105</team2></spread><total><points>130</points><over>-105</over><under>-105</under></total><teamtotal><team1><points>62</points><over>-110</over><under>-110</under></team1><team2><points>68</points><over>-110</over><under>-110</under></team2></teamtotal><score><team1></team1><team2></team2><winner></winner></score></line></game><game><id>820848</id><header>New Orleans Pelicans At Toronto Raptors</header><sporttype>Basketball</sporttype><sportsubtype>NBA</sportsubtype> <gamedate>2015-01-18 15:35:00</gamedate><last_update>2015-01-18 12:42:04</last_update><void>0</void><last_pitcher_change></last_pitcher_change><team1><rotnum>801</rotnum><name>New Orleans Pelicans</name><pitcher></pitcher></team1><team2><rotnum>802</rotnum><name>Toronto Raptors</name><pitcher></pitcher> </team2><line><periodnum>3</periodnum><perioddesc>1st Quarter</perioddesc><wagercutoff>2015-01-18 15:30:00</wagercutoff><money><team1>170</team1><team2>-200</team2><draw>0</draw></money><spread><points>-3</points><team1>-115</team1><team2>-105</team2></spread><total><points>49</points><over>-110</over><under>-110</under></total><teamtotal><team1><points>23</points><over>-110</over><under>-110</under></team1><team2><points>26</points><over>-110</over><under>-110</under></team2></teamtotal><score><team1></team1><team2></team2><winner></winner></score></line></game><game><id>820849</id><header>New Orleans Pelicans At Toronto Raptors</header><sporttype>Basketball</sporttype><sportsubtype>NBA</sportsubtype> <gamedate>2015-01-18 15:35:00</gamedate><last_update>2015-01-18 12:48:05</last_update><void>0</void><last_pitcher_change></last_pitcher_change><team1><rotnum>801</rotnum><name>New Orleans Pelicans</name><pitcher></pitcher></team1><team2><rotnum>802</rotnum><name>Toronto Raptors</name><pitcher></pitcher> </team2><line><periodnum>4</periodnum><perioddesc>2nd Quarter</perioddesc><wagercutoff>2015-01-18 15:30:00</wagercutoff><money><team1>0</team1><team2>0</team2><draw>0</draw></money><spread><points>-2</points><team1>-110</team1><team2>-110</team2></spread><total><points>48.5</points><over>-110</over><under>-110</under></total><teamtotal><team1><points>0</points><over>0</over><under>0</under></team1><team2><points>0</points><over>0</over><under>0</under></team2></teamtotal><score><team1></team1><team2></team2><winner></winner></score></line></game><game><id>820839</id><header>New Orleans Pelicans At Toronto Raptors</header><sporttype>Basketball</sporttype><sportsubtype>NBA</sportsubtype> <gamedate>2015-01-18 15:35:00</gamedate><last_update>2015-01-18 12:39:04</last_update><void>0</void><last_pitcher_change></last_pitcher_change><team1><rotnum>801</rotnum><name>New Orleans Pelicans</name><pitcher></pitcher></team1><team2><rotnum>802</rotnum><name>Toronto Raptors</name><pitcher></pitcher> </team2><line><periodnum>0</periodnum><perioddesc>Game</perioddesc><wagercutoff>2015-01-18 15:35:00</wagercutoff><money><team1>380</team1><team2>-430</team2><draw>0</draw></money><spread><points>-9</points><team1>-105</team1><team2>-105</team2></spread><total><points>203.5</points><over>-105</over><under>-105</under></total><teamtotal><team1><points>97.5</points><over>-110</over><under>-110</under></team1><team2><points>106</points><over>-110</over><under>-110</under></team2></teamtotal><score><team1></team1><team2></team2><winner></winner></score></line></game><game><id>820841</id><header>New Orleans Pelicans At Toronto Raptors</header><sporttype>Basketball</sporttype><sportsubtype>NBA</sportsubtype> <gamedate>2015-01-18 15:35:00</gamedate><last_update>2015-01-18 12:36:04</last_update><void>0</void><last_pitcher_change></last_pitcher_change><team1><rotnum>801</rotnum><name>New Orleans Pelicans</name><pitcher></pitcher></team1><team2><rotnum>802</rotnum><name>Toronto Raptors</name><pitcher></pitcher> </team2><line><periodnum>1</periodnum><perioddesc>1st Half</perioddesc><wagercutoff>2015-01-18 15:30:00</wagercutoff><money><team1>220</team1><team2>-260</team2><draw>0</draw></money><spread><points>-4.5</points><team1>-105</team1><team2>-115</team2></spread><total><points>98</points><over>-110</over><under>-110</under></total><teamtotal><team1><points>47</points><over>-110</over><under>-110</under></team1><team2><points>51</points><over>-110</over><under>-110</under></team2></teamtotal><score><team1></team1><team2></team2><winner></winner></score></line></game><game><id>820472</id><header>Missouri State At Northern Iowa</header><sporttype>Basketball</sporttype><sportsubtype>College</sportsubtype> <gamedate>2015-01-18 16:00:00</gamedate><last_update>2015-01-18 12:24:04</last_update><void>0</void><last_pitcher_change></last_pitcher_change><team1><rotnum>811</rotnum><name>Missouri State</name><pitcher></pitcher></team1><team2><rotnum>812</rotnum><name>Northern Iowa</name><pitcher></pitcher> </team2><line><periodnum>0</periodnum><perioddesc>Game</perioddesc><wagercutoff>2015-01-18 16:00:00</wagercutoff><money><team1>1000</team1><team2>-1500</team2><draw>0</draw></money><spread><points>-14.5</points><team1>-105</team1><team2>-105</team2></spread><total><points>116</points><over>-105</over><under>-105</under></total><teamtotal><team1><points>50</points><over>-110</over><under>-110</under></team1><team2><points>66</points><over>-110</over><under>-110</under></team2></teamtotal><score><team1></team1><team2></team2><winner></winner></score></line></game><game><id>820803</id><header>Missouri State At Northern Iowa</header><sporttype>Basketball</sporttype><sportsubtype>College</sportsubtype> <gamedate>2015-01-18 16:00:00</gamedate><last_update>2015-01-18 12:06:04</last_update><void>0</void><last_pitcher_change></last_pitcher_change><team1><rotnum>811</rotnum><name>Missouri State</name><pitcher></pitcher></team1><team2><rotnum>812</rotnum><name>Northern Iowa</name><pitcher></pitcher> </team2><line><periodnum>1</periodnum><perioddesc>1st Half</perioddesc><wagercutoff>2015-01-18 15:55:00</wagercutoff><money><team1>500</team1><team2>-700</team2><draw>0</draw></money><spread><points>-8.5</points><team1>-110</team1><team2>-110</team2></spread><total><points>53.5</points><over>-110</over><under>-110</under></total><teamtotal><team1><points>22.5</points><over>-110</over><under>-110</under></team1><team2><points>31</points><over>-110</over><under>-110</under></team2></teamtotal><score><team1></team1><team2></team2><winner></winner></score></line></game><game><id>820488</id><header>Fairfield At Monmouth</header><sporttype>Basketball</sporttype><sportsubtype>College</sportsubtype> <gamedate>2015-01-18 16:30:00</gamedate><last_update>2015-01-18 12:03:04</last_update><void>0</void><last_pitcher_change></last_pitcher_change><team1><rotnum>833</rotnum><name>Fairfield</name><pitcher></pitcher></team1><team2><rotnum>834</rotnum><name>Monmouth</name><pitcher></pitcher> </team2><line><periodnum>0</periodnum><perioddesc>Game</perioddesc><wagercutoff>2015-01-18 16:30:00</wagercutoff><money><team1>280</team1><team2>-310</team2><draw>0</draw></money><spread><points>-7</points><team1>-102</team1><team2>-108</team2></spread><total><points>118</points><over>-110</over><under>-110</under></total><teamtotal><team1><points>0</points><over>0</over><under>0</under></team1><team2><points>0</points><over>0</over><under>0</under></team2></teamtotal><score><team1></team1><team2></team2><winner></winner></score></line></game><game><id>820475</id><header>Boise State At New Mexico</header><sporttype>Basketball</sporttype><sportsubtype>College</sportsubtype> <gamedate>2015-01-18 18:00:00</gamedate><last_update>2015-01-18 12:30:12</last_update><void>0</void><last_pitcher_change></last_pitcher_change><team1><rotnum>817</rotnum><name>Boise State</name><pitcher></pitcher></team1><team2><rotnum>818</rotnum><name>New Mexico</name><pitcher></pitcher> </team2><line><periodnum>0</periodnum><perioddesc>Game</perioddesc><wagercutoff>2015-01-18 18:00:00</wagercutoff><money><team1>215</team1><team2>-235</team2><draw>0</draw></money><spread><points>-5.5</points><team1>-105</team1><team2>-105</team2></spread><total><points>120</points><over>-106</over><under>-104</under></total><teamtotal><team1><points>58</points><over>-110</over><under>-110</under></team1><team2><points>62.5</points><over>-110</over><under>-110</under></team2></teamtotal><score><team1></team1><team2></team2><winner></winner></score></line></game><game><id>820471</id><header>Loyola Chicago At Southern Illinois</header><sporttype>Basketball</sporttype><sportsubtype>College</sportsubtype> <gamedate>2015-01-18 18:00:00</gamedate><last_update>2015-01-18 12:24:04</last_update><void>0</void><last_pitcher_change></last_pitcher_change><team1><rotnum>809</rotnum><name>Loyola Chicago</name><pitcher></pitcher></team1><team2><rotnum>810</rotnum><name>Southern Illinois</name><pitcher></pitcher> </team2><line><periodnum>0</periodnum><perioddesc>Game</perioddesc><wagercutoff>2015-01-18 18:00:00</wagercutoff><money><team1>-105</team1><team2>-105</team2><draw>0</draw></money><spread><points>-1</points><team1>-112</team1><team2>102</team2></spread><total><points>115</points><over>-110</over><under>-110</under></total><teamtotal><team1><points>0</points><over>0</over><under>0</under></team1><team2><points>0</points><over>0</over><under>0</under></team2></teamtotal><score><team1></team1><team2></team2><winner></winner></score></line></game><game><id>820802</id><header>Loyola Chicago At Southern Illinois</header><sporttype>Basketball</sporttype><sportsubtype>College</sportsubtype> <gamedate>2015-01-18 18:00:00</gamedate><last_update>2015-01-18 12:21:04</last_update><void>0</void><last_pitcher_change></last_pitcher_change><team1><rotnum>809</rotnum><name>Loyola Chicago</name><pitcher></pitcher></team1><team2><rotnum>810</rotnum><name>Southern Illinois</name><pitcher></pitcher> </team2><line><periodnum>1</periodnum><perioddesc>1st Half</perioddesc><wagercutoff>2015-01-18 17:55:00</wagercutoff><money><team1>-110</team1><team2>-110</team2><draw>0</draw></money><spread><points>-0.5</points><team1>-120</team1><team2>100</team2></spread><total><points>0</points><over>0</over><under>0</under></total><teamtotal><team1><points>0</points><over>0</over><under>0</under></team1><team2><points>0</points><over>0</over><under>0</under></team2></teamtotal><score><team1></team1><team2></team2><winner></winner></score></line></game><game><id>820479</id><header>Dallas Stars At Chicago Blackhawks</header><sporttype>Hockey</sporttype><sportsubtype>NHL</sportsubtype> <gamedate>2015-01-18 18:05:00</gamedate><last_update>2015-01-18 11:54:04</last_update><void>0</void><last_pitcher_change></last_pitcher_change><team1><rotnum>53</rotnum><name>Dallas Stars</name><pitcher></pitcher></team1><team2><rotnum>54</rotnum><name>Chicago Blackhawks</name><pitcher></pitcher> </team2><line><periodnum>0</periodnum><perioddesc>Game</perioddesc><wagercutoff>2015-01-18 18:05:00</wagercutoff><money><team1>225</team1><team2>-245</team2><draw>0</draw></money><spread><points>-1.5</points><team1>-135</team1><team2>125</team2></spread><total><points>5.5</points><over>-124</over><under>114</under></total><teamtotal><team1><points>2.5</points><over>110</over><under>-130</under></team1><team2><points>3.5</points><over>105</over><under>-125</under></team2></teamtotal><score><team1></team1><team2></team2><winner></winner></score></line></game><game><id>820468</id><header>Oklahoma City Thunder At Orlando Magic</header><sporttype>Basketball</sporttype><sportsubtype>NBA</sportsubtype> <gamedate>2015-01-18 18:05:00</gamedate><last_update>2015-01-18 12:33:05</last_update><void>0</void><last_pitcher_change></last_pitcher_change><team1><rotnum>803</rotnum><name>Oklahoma City Thunder</name><pitcher></pitcher></team1><team2><rotnum>804</rotnum><name>Orlando Magic</name><pitcher></pitcher> </team2><line><periodnum>0</periodnum><perioddesc>Game</perioddesc><wagercutoff>2015-01-18 18:05:00</wagercutoff><money><team1>-470</team1><team2>415</team2><draw>0</draw></money><spread><points>9.5</points><team1>-103</team1><team2>-107</team2></spread><total><points>213.5</points><over>-105</over><under>-105</under></total><teamtotal><team1><points>111.5</points><over>-110</over><under>-110</under></team1><team2><points>102</points><over>-110</over><under>-110</under></team2></teamtotal><score><team1></team1><team2></team2><winner></winner></score></line></game><game><id>820852</id><header>Oklahoma City Thunder At Orlando Magic</header><sporttype>Basketball</sporttype><sportsubtype>NBA</sportsubtype> <gamedate>2015-01-18 18:05:00</gamedate><last_update>2015-01-18 12:33:05</last_update><void>0</void><last_pitcher_change></last_pitcher_change><team1><rotnum>803</rotnum><name>Oklahoma City Thunder</name><pitcher></pitcher></team1><team2><rotnum>804</rotnum><name>Orlando Magic</name><pitcher></pitcher> </team2><line><periodnum>4</periodnum><perioddesc>2nd Quarter</perioddesc><wagercutoff>2015-01-18 18:00:00</wagercutoff><money><team1>0</team1><team2>0</team2><draw>0</draw></money><spread><points>2</points><team1>-110</team1><team2>-110</team2></spread><total><points>52.5</points><over>-110</over><under>-110</under></total><teamtotal><team1><points>0</points><over>0</over><under>0</under></team1><team2><points>0</points><over>0</over><under>0</under></team2></teamtotal><score><team1></team1><team2></team2><winner></winner></score></line></game><game><id>820851</id><header>Oklahoma City Thunder At Orlando Magic</header><sporttype>Basketball</sporttype><sportsubtype>NBA</sportsubtype> <gamedate>2015-01-18 18:05:00</gamedate><last_update>2015-01-18 12:45:06</last_update><void>0</void><last_pitcher_change></last_pitcher_change><team1><rotnum>803</rotnum><name>Oklahoma City Thunder</name><pitcher></pitcher></team1><team2><rotnum>804</rotnum><name>Orlando Magic</name><pitcher></pitcher> </team2><line><periodnum>3</periodnum><perioddesc>1st Quarter</perioddesc><wagercutoff>2015-01-18 18:00:00</wagercutoff><money><team1>-220</team1><team2>180</team2><draw>0</draw></money><spread><points>3</points><team1>-110</team1><team2>-110</team2></spread><total><points>54.5</points><over>-110</over><under>-110</under></total><teamtotal><team1><points>28.5</points><over>-110</over><under>-110</under></team1><team2><points>26</points><over>-110</over><under>-110</under></team2></teamtotal><score><team1></team1><team2></team2><winner></winner></score></line></game><game><id>820799</id><header>Oklahoma City Thunder At Orlando Magic</header><sporttype>Basketball</sporttype><sportsubtype>NBA</sportsubtype> <gamedate>2015-01-18 18:05:00</gamedate><last_update>2015-01-18 12:24:04</last_update><void>0</void><last_pitcher_change></last_pitcher_change><team1><rotnum>803</rotnum><name>Oklahoma City Thunder</name><pitcher></pitcher></team1><team2><rotnum>804</rotnum><name>Orlando Magic</name><pitcher></pitcher> </team2><line><periodnum>1</periodnum><perioddesc>1st Half</perioddesc><wagercutoff>2015-01-18 18:00:00</wagercutoff><money><team1>-290</team1><team2>245</team2><draw>0</draw></money><spread><points>5</points><team1>-110</team1><team2>-110</team2></spread><total><points>108</points><over>-105</over><under>-115...
```

which have no tag `FILE` or `file`.

`$response['FILE'];// the 'FILE' is not exists`

Comment: Im sorry i don't understand you what you mean the 'FILE' is not exists?